# Git - I made many changes at once -- now I want to break it down into one commit per file - how?

Tags: git

I've been working on my code base for a few days now.  I've modified about 15 files, making various changes to each.  Now I'd like to commit all my work, but I would like to break down my work into multiple smaller commits.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

With `git gui` you can select which changes to stage (staging means preparing for the next commit). I find that to be the easiest way, especially if you just want to commit individual parts of a file (even down to single lines).

Comment: adding on, I would recommend sourcetree: http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

i recently switched and have found it to be great for things like that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to commit all changes in one file do `git add <filename>` followed by `git commit`.

Or you can use `git add`'s interactive mode (with the `-i` option), so you choose individual patches from a file to commit.

On a separate note, personally I make it a habit to commit changes often; you can always combine commits later if necessary. Remember that a commit is the smallest unit you can roll back. If you had to undo one small bit in a commit containing a couple of days of coding, it would be more time consuming and error-prone to fix. My suggestion would be to commit your changes *at least* at the end of the day.